# Xubuntu 22.04 terminal with Ctrl V paste

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce4-terminal

I have installed Xubuntu 22.04, and the keyboard shortcuts for cut and paste are `ctrl`+ `shift` + `c` and `ctrl` + `shift` + `v`.

My other applications Pycharm for example use `ctrl`  + `c` and `ctrl` + `v`.

Can I either make the Xfce terminal use these shortcuts, or can someone recommend a terminal I can install that uses these shortcuts?

Comment: You can't use Ctrl+C in Uubntu terminal for copying, because it is used for other purposes.

Comment: I can in Pycharms built in terminal. Why not in this? I used to be able to.

Comment: The historic use of ctrl+c is to abort (kill) execution of a running program. It's still used for that important function. Much later, GUI developers made a foolish choice to *also* use the killing key-combination for "copy." We have lived with the consequences: Two generations of misguided youth who learned GUI first, imprinted upon the foolish choice, and demand that the foolish choice be forced upon everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions to remap `ctrl-c` to copy and `ctrl-v` to paste may be found here: [How to set ctrl+c to copy, ctrl+v to paste and ctrl+shift+c to kill process in xfce4-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271150/how-to-set-ctrlc-to-copy-ctrlv-to-paste-and-ctrlshiftc-to-kill-process-in-x).

Fortunately `ctrl-shift-c` works to kill a running process anyway.